# Measure length between an element and window margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to measure pixels between an **html element** and current **viewport border**.

For a example, if we have a **DIV** -

```
|--------------------------|
|                          |
|                          | 
|       |=========|        |
|   L   |   DIV   |    R   |
|<----->|         |<------>|
|       |=========|        |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
```

I know how to measure current viewport,

```
var $w = $(window);
return {
    l: $w.scrollLeft(),
    t: $w.scrollTop(),
    w: $w.width(),
    h: $w.height() 
}
```

Is there a way to get **R** and **L** values in pixels? it shouldn't be element and screen border, it should be element and viewport border.

Comment: Doesn't `.position()` return the position of an element relative to document.body? -- neverminde it's `.offset()`

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) might be useful.

Comment: I tried, it returns pixels between element and window border, not element and viewport border.

Comment: @Teemu - tried, it won't give correct measurement when you resize the window.

Comment: What's the difference between window border and viewport border? Please _read_ the article I've linked.

Comment: @Teemu when you resize the window, length between viewport border changes where window border is not. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really mean with windows and viewports. `getBoundingClientRect()` gives you measures related to top-left corner of the viewport... Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Btc/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this , but it will give offset relative to its parent, so if its parent is  `body` you will get desired result, Incase if not then get the offset of its parent too and add it

```
function getOffset(id)
{

    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    var left = parseInt(ele.style.left || ele.offsetLeft);
    var right = parseInt(ele.style.right || ele.offsetRight);

    alert(left + " " +right);
}
```